# How to optimize process of outlook files (*msg) conversion to .pdf?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pdf, conversion

The aim is to convert several messages from Microsoft Outlook (2003 and/or 2007 versions) to .pdf files.

Condition: One message should generate a corresponding single pdf file. If possible, pdf file should be named with date format YYYY-MM-DD (e.g. 2011-02-16.pdf).

The current process, limited by softwares such as CutePDF, requires the conversion performed one message at a time.

I'm looking for a solution that allows the conversion of several messages at once, but under the condition abovementioned (mainly: one message = one pdf file).

Comment: Write an app to do it. Your constraints are very specific to Outlook and may be too narrow to find a reasonable solution.